# how can i grab the alias of every field with "select *"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**How can I list all the field names of my query like so:**

```
table1.field1
,table1.field2
,table1.field3
,table2.field1
,table2.field2
etc
```

from this select statement:

```
Select
            *

            from
            Status s
            Inner Join Residents r
            ON r.RES_ID = s.RES_ID
            Left Join REPSResidents rr
            ON rr.MainPeopleIDY = r.RES_PeopleIDY
            Inner Join Associate u
            ON s.STA_User = u.USR_ID
            Inner Join KSLSQL1.[RPS-201065-000].dbo.people p
            ON r.RES_PeopleIDY = p.PeopleIDY
            Where.......
```

my issue is that in SSRS, i cannot just do `select *` because there are several fields from multiple tables which repeat.

so i would need instead a listing of all of the fields that are returned.

is this possible?

Comment: List them out using the alias  SELECT s.field, s.field, r.field, etc.

Comment: @Goat_CO there about 100 fields, i dont want to do that

Comment: Can't post my answer for some reason...

Comment: you can make it a comment :)

Comment: Couldn't paste it here either, very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT t.name +'_' + c.name
    FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
         sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name = 'Residents'
```

Comment: And just Union them all together.